# can the order of code make this program faster?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

Hi this is my first post, I am learning how to write code so technically I am a newbie.

I am learning python I am still at the very basics,  I was getting to Know the if statement and I tried to mix it with another concepts(function definition,input,variables) in order to get a wider vision of python, I wrote some code without a specific idea of what I wanted to do I just wanted to mix everything that I have learned so far so probably I over do it and its not practical, it "works" when I run it.

The question that I have its not about how to do it more efficient or with less code it is about the order of code in all programming in general. Here I'll show 2 different order of code that gives the same result with exactly the same code(but with different order).

on (1) I define a function on the first line.
on (2) I define the same function closer to when I use it on line 5.

which one is faster? is defining a function "closer" to when I need it impractical for the complexity of larger programs(but does it make it faster), or defining a function "far" from where I need it makes a larger program slower when running(but also more practical).

(1)

```
def t(n1,n2):
    v=n1-n2
    return abs(v)
a = int(input('how old are you? \n'))
b = int(input('how old is your best friend? \n'))

c=t(a,b)

if a==b:
    print ('you are both the same age')

else:
    print('you are not the same age\nthe difference of years is %s year(s)' % c)

input()
```

(2)

```
a = int(input('how old are you? \n'))
b = int(input('how old is your best friend? \n'))

def t(n1,n2):
    v=n1-n2
    return abs(v)

c=t(a,b)

if a==b:
    print ('you are both the same age')

else:
    print('you are not the same age\nthe difference of years is %s year(s)' % c)

input()
```

Comment: Don't worry about speed until you have something to worry about. If you have a big piece of code that runs too slow for your liking, first see if you can come up with a better algorithm.

Comment: @RolandSmith I wasn't worried I just wanted to know if it makes a difference.

Comment: If you want to measure speed, you should use a [profiler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html).

Answer (score 1):

The function definition must be located above the function call, but the distance between the function definition and the function call does not matter (as the function code would already be loaded).

One way to make your program faster is to avoid repeated calculations that produce the same result, by performing the calculation once, storing the result in a variable and using that variable whenever you need the result.

For example, suppose your program handles a very large tuple. If `len(veryLargeTuple)` occurs many times in the code, Python will repeatedly try to determine the length of the very large tuple. This is a waste of time because a tuple is immutable, so its length would not change, and finding the length of a very large tuple may take some time. It would be faster to store the result of `len(veryLargeTuple)` in a variable `veryLargeTupleLength` and use `veryLargeTupleLength` whenever you need the length of the very large tuple (looking up the value of a variable is a very fast operation).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make the slightest bit of difference. Do whatever is most readable.

Comment: The asymptotic performance of the algorithm is O(1) and thus cannot be improved. However, there are as number of possible way to slightly improve the actual run-time of the algorithm when the algorithm is run a number of times. However, the change you made in this specific case shouldn't have much of an effect.